# Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have an issue with my Ruby on Rails application. So, there are workers, which are listening for different rabbitMQ topics. Each worker make some changes it it's DB (mariaDB) table and in the end update 'last_connection' field in common object 'device', where I have issue.

This is one worker:

```
  include Sneakers::Worker
  # This worker will connect to "queue" queue
  # env is set to nil since by default the actuall queue name would be
  # "queue_development"
  from_queue "sensor_log"

  # work method receives message payload in raw format
  def work(raw_message)
    logger.info ("sensor_log " + raw_message)
    msg = JSON.parse(raw_message)

   # msg = {"deviceId" => 102,"timestamp" => 1487318555,"sensor" => 5, "values" => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "isNewSensor" => false, "logDelayed" => false}
    begin
      @device = Device.find(msg["deviceId"])

   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        # Initialize
        timestamp = Time.at(msg["timestamp"])

        MiddlewareLog.create(
          device_id: msg["deviceId"],
          message: JSON.pretty_generate(msg),
          queue: MiddlewareLog.queues[:sensor_log]
        )

        if(msg["ext_brd_type"] == 6)

          logger.info ("Logging external sensors lm2, lm4, lm4")
          # Logging external sensors lm2, lm4, lm4
          Sensors::SENSORS_EXT.map do |code|
            SensorLog.create(
                device_id: msg["deviceId"],
                sensor: code,
                state: msg[code],
                value: msg[code],
                is_delayed: msg["logDelayed"],
                created_at: timestamp
            )
          end

        else

          logger.info ("Logging native sensors")
          # Logging native
          device_sensors = @device.new_version? ? Sensors::SENSORS_CODES_NEW : Sensors::SENSORS_CODES
          @sensors = device_sensors.reject{|code, sensor| code & msg["sensor"] == 0}
          @sensors.map do |code, sensor|
            SensorLog.create(
              device_id: msg["deviceId"],
              sensor: sensor[:name],
              state: sensor[:state],
              value: msg["values"][sensor[:bit_position]],
              is_delayed: msg["logDelayed"],
              created_at: timestamp
            )
          end
          Rollbar.warning("Unknown device sensor", :message => msg, :sensor => msg["sensor"]) if @sensors.empty?

          @device.update_sensors_state(msg["values"]) if @sensors.any?

        end

        # Avoid updated_at deadlock
        @device.save!(touch: false)
      end


      # Touch updated_at and last_connection_at
      @device.touch(:last_connection_at)
      ack! # we need to let queue know that message was received
    rescue => exception
      logger.error ("sensors_log exception:")
      logger.error exception
      Rollbar.error(exception, :message => msg)
      requeue!
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the second one:

```
class SystemLogsWorker
  include Sneakers::Worker
  # This worker will connect to "queue" queue
  # env is set to nil since by default the actuall queue name would be
  # "queue_development"
  from_queue "system_log"

  # @logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  # @logger.level = Logger::INFO

  # work method receives message payload in raw format
  def work(raw_message)
    # @logger.info raw_message
    logger.info ("system_log " + raw_message)
    msg = JSON.parse(raw_message)

    # msg = {"deviceId":102,"timestamp":1487318555,"system":2069,"logDelayed":false,"fault_code":1}
    begin
      @device = Device.find(msg["deviceId"])

      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        # Initialize
        timestamp = Time.at(msg["timestamp"])

        MiddlewareLog.create(
            device_id: msg["deviceId"],
            message: JSON.pretty_generate(msg),
            queue: MiddlewareLog.queues[:system_log]
        )

        @system = Systems::EVENTS_CODES[msg["system"]]

        # @logger.warn("Unknown device system", :message => msg, :system => msg[:system]) unless @system
        # logger.warn("Unknown device system", :message => msg, :system => msg["system"]) unless @system
        # Rollbar.warning("Unknown device system", :message => msg, :system => msg["system"]) unless @system
        logger.warn("Unknown device system. Message:" + raw_message) unless @system
        Rollbar.warning("Unknown device system. Message:" + raw_message) unless @system
        # Loggin
        system_log = SystemLog.create(
            device_id: msg["deviceId"],
            system: @system[:name],
            state: @system[:state],
            is_delayed: msg["logDelayed"],
            fault_code: msg["fault_code"],
            created_at: timestamp
        ) if @system

        @device.update_systems_state(system_log) if @system

        # Avoid updated_at deadlock
        @device.save!(touch: false)
      end

      # Touch updated_at and last_connection_at
      @device.touch(:last_connection_at)
      ack! # we need to let queue know that message was received
    rescue => exception
      logger.error ("system_log exception:")
      logger.error exception
      Rollbar.error(exception, :message => msg)
      requeue!
    end
  end
end
```

In the runtime I get the message:

> 2020-06-18T11:09:08Z p-13299 t-gmvtsrzac ERROR: sensors_log exception:
>   2020-06-18T11:09:08Z p-13299 t-gmvtsrzac ERROR: Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: UPDATE `devices` SET `devices`.`updated_at` = '2020-06-18 11:09:08', `devices`.`last_connection_at` = '2020-06-18 11:09:08' WHERE `devices`.`id` = 3024
>
> 2020-06-18T11:09:08Z p-13299 t-gmvtsq74w ERROR: system_log exception:
>   2020-06-18T11:09:08Z p-13299 t-gmvtsq74w ERROR: Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: UPDATE `devices` SET `devices`.`updated_at` = '2020-06-18 11:09:08', `devices`.`last_connection_at` = '2020-06-18 11:09:08' WHERE `devices`.`id` = 3024

I think that the problem point in
`@device.touch(:last_connection_at)`, because in one time both workers trying to update one table row. 
I'm not so good with ruby and will be glad to any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a lock within the transaction before updating the database data?

```
@device.lock!
@device.save!(touch: false)
@device.touch(:last_connection_at)
```

You can also start a lock and transaction at the same time using with_lock:

```
@device = Device.find(msg["deviceId"])

@device.with_lock do
  # your block here
end
```

As described in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html